# how can I solve this circular dependent imports in order to execute many to one insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following two models in several files:

**routes/camera/model.py**

```
from services.db import db
from dataclasses import dataclass
from routes.project.models import Project

@dataclass
class Camera(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cameras'
    id: int
    name: str
    project_id: int
    url: str

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique=True, nullable=False)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'), nullable=False)
    
db.create_all()
```

**routes/project/model.py**

```
from services.db import db
from dataclasses import dataclass
from routes.camera.models import Camera

@dataclass
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id: int
    name: str

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    cameras = db.relationship(Camera, backref='projects')
    
db.create_all()
```

The problem is that I need make a insert by project name in camera in order to do this I have the following approach:

```
def create_camera(name: str, url:str, project_name:str):
    project = Project(name=project_name)
    camera = Camera(name=name, project_id=project, url=url)
    db.session.add(camera)
    db.session.commit()
```

but I get  a circular dependant and I cannot make this insert

So, how can I solve this problem (circular dependent import) or the insert in order to avoid to instantiate the Project class?

Thanks

Comment: I would place both models in a single model.py

Comment: I use service classes that use the models and the models just consist of the class and columns.  Then you'd import the Camera and Project classes into a service such as CameraService and there you would create_camera.  This sort of setup works great with a dependency injection framework.  I used to use methods on the models or functions in with the models but that usually always ended up with circular dependencies.